# Send mail through cfmail with one connection

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-9, cfmail

I ran into an issue where my mail server only accepts 100 connections to the server every 5 minutes. My current code loops over my database, calling cfmail for each person on the list. I suppose the problem is im opening a new connection each time I use cfmail?

```
<CFLOOP QUERY="Customer" >

    <!---send mail to Admin ----->
     <cfmail to = "#cstEmail#"
      from = "#FORM.fromAddressEmail#"
      subject = "#FORM.subjectEmail#"
      server = "#var.mailserver#"
      port= "#var.mailport#"
      username="#var.mailuser#"
      password="#var.mailpass#"
      failto="#var.failEmail#
      type="html"         
       >
```

What I ran into was only 100 mails were being sent at a time, the rest were sent to cf's undelivered folder.  I would send them to spool and again 100 would get through..

Now, I've read in older versions of cf there is a checkbox in cf administrator to "maintain connection"  -Im running cf9 and dont see this option.

Would using cfmail's query attribute, force cfmail to only connect to the mail server once to send all the emails?

```
<cfmail query="Customer"
from = "#FORM.fromAddressEmail#"
to = "#cstEmail#"
subject = "#FORM.subjectEmail#">
```

Im not even sure how to test this without sending a couple hundred emails.  Any thoughts if this is a viable solution to the problem?

Thanks for your help!
Biscotti

Comment: what version of CF do you have?

Comment: Version  9,0,1,274733  
Edition  Developer

Comment: Is your email such that you can send the same email to multiple recipients? Maybe put all the recipients in the bcc attribute? You can add multiple recipients as a comma separated list.

Comment: @Goyuix that's usually not a good idea... https://www.google.ca/search?q=bcc+spam

Comment: Ok so "Maintain Connection to Mail Server" is Enterprise Edition feature only.  Im still curious if using QUERY in CFMAIL will keep the connection open?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up compromising by using a scheduled task to move the files every 5 minutes back over to the Spool dir from the Undelivr dir.  Im not thrilled with this solution, but it works.

Thanks to Russ's Respooler extension. http://cfrespooler.riaforge.org/

Comment: Another problem with this solution, is that when the spooler bottlenecks at the mail server-it takes about an hour for all the mail to get through - AND I cannot send other email through this server during that time!

Answer (score 0):

By using the above code to call the QUERY within CFMAIL I only succeeded in speeding up the client side process. The mail server still rejected the mail after the 100th connection - leading me to determine there is no server side benefit to this method over simply looping CFMAIL like in my first example.  I seems the only answer is to run the code within the enterprise edition of the cf environment, one that has the "maintain connection" feature enabled.